# Change paint type android drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas

I wrote a painting app. I can change the color and thickness but don't know how to change the paint type like pen/ pencil or brush ? how can I change it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one link that might help you and might get you what you are looking for..

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-interface-creation--mobile-19021

Comment: it tells all thing except pen type :)